# login date in spring security plugin for Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

i'm using **spring security plugin** , i want to save the user's login date in the DB so i wrote the below in the config file :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent= { e, appCtx ->
com.app.utils.UserActivity.withTransaction {
    def user = com.app.utils.UserActivity.findByUser(com.app.security.Users.get(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id))
    if (!user)
    { 
        new com.app.utils.UserActivity(user:user,userLoggedIn:new Date(),userLoggedOut: null).save(failOnError:true)

    }

    else
    {
        user.userLoggedIn= new Date()
        user.userLoggedOut=null
        user.save(failOnError:true)

    }

 }
}
```

the issue is that `appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id` is always returning `null` , and are there any events for the `logout` action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to get the pricipal is from the authentication event like this:

`e.getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`

Comment: it worked fine , is there any event for the `logout` ?

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation which explains how to add your own logout handler since there isn't an event like login: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#logoutHandlers